# Control which iOS notifications to display

Tags: ios, push-notification

We have iOS push notifications configured and running. However, we would like the user to select which categories are interesting to receive and which are not important and would like to omit receiving those notifications.

Is there any way to do this through Apple push notification itself rather than through the server sending the notifications? (We can change the sent JSON). Can the iPhone send which categories it would like to receive and which are not needed by registering them to Apple? Other choice, can we interrupt the push notification before being shown and decide whether it should be shown or not through a delegate? So far, I can't find an available method to do either.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you tried to register with categories and make sure what server add `category` in `aps` payload?

Comment: Can I disable entirely specific categories from receiving a notification by not registering them? The server already sends the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is not from the client side. If you want a solution that works 100% of the time you will need to do something on a server which only sends the types of push notifications the user subscribes to.

If your App is in background there is no concept of "categories" of PUSH notifications and you have no control over if they show up in the notification center.

You can examine inbound push when the App is in the foreground and decide on the basis of some meta data to display or not, but that is not a 100% solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that I was limited here without server's interference.